# React Native: Passing Params to a different Screen using navigationOptions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to set my header title to my passed param.

So basically I have two files that are communicating.

**Categories.js:**

```
import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummy-data';

const CategoriesScreen = props => {

    const renderGridItem = itemData => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate('CategoryMeals', { categoryId: itemData.item.id });
            }} >
                <View style={styles.gridItem}>
                    <Text>{itemData.item.title}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };
```

On this file I am passing a params `categoryId` so that I can use it on the `CategoryMealsScreen.js`:

**CategoryMealsScreen.js**

```
import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummy-data';

const CategoryMealsScreen = props => {

    const catId = props.route.params.categoryId;

    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find(cat => cat.id === catId);

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Text>Category Meals Screen</Text>
            <Text>{selectedCategory.title}</Text>
            <Button title="Go to Details" onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate('MealDetail');
            }} />


            <Button title="Go Back" onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.goBack();
            }} />
        </View>
    );
}

CategoryMealsScreen.navigationOptions = navigationData => {
    const catId = props.route.params.categoryId;
    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find(cat => cat.id === catId);

    return { 
        headerTitle: selectedCategory.title
     }
};
```

Focus on this code below:

```
CategoryMealsScreen.navigationOptions = navigationData => {
        const catId = props.route.params.categoryId;
        const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find(cat => cat.id === catId);
    
        return { 
            headerTitle: selectedCategory.title
         }
    };
```

Here I am trying to pull up the title from my dummy data to use it as my header title using `navigationOptions` but its not working. It doesn't change the header title at all.

What am I missing here? How can I fix this?

**PS. I am using React Navigation version 5**

EDIT: I organize all of my naviation inside a MealsNavigator.js file and then render all on App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';

import Colors from '../constants/colors';

const MealsNav = createStackNavigator();

const MealsNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MealsNav.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                    },
                    headerTintColor: '#fff',
                    headerTitleStyle: {
                        fontSize: 17
                    }
                }}
            >
                <MealsNav.Screen
                    name="Categories"
                    component={CategoriesScreen}
                    options={{
                        title: 'Meals Categories'
                    }}
                />
                <MealsNav.Screen name="CategoryMeals" component={CategoryMealsScreen} />
                <MealsNav.Screen name="MealDetail" component={MealDetailScreen} />
            </MealsNav.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default MealsNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Navigation version5 you can do the below
When creating the stack you can provide the options

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="CategoryMealsScreen"
    component={CategoryMealsScreen}
    options={({ route }) => {
      const catId = route.params.categoryId;
      const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

      return {
        title: selectedCategory.title,
      };
      
    }}
  />
```

Update

You can use the static options like below

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="CategoryMealsScreen"
  component={CategoryMealsScreen}
  options={CategoryMealsScreen.navigationOptions}
/>;
```

Comment: Woulld this work on the same file? Cause basically I have a different file for my navigation.

Comment: This is in the place where you setup navigation generally the app.js file but the way to setup from same file is to use navigation.setOptions inside the useEffect which will make things complex

Comment: It did not work to me. Wondering if there is an option like the code on `CategoryMealsScreen.js` where In I can use the class and from the pull up the params.

Comment: The second option should work with a class component and its title not headerTitle, can you try that ?

Comment: Ok I take my word back. So basically I tried the first option. So instead of passsing it down to the next component (From Categories.js to CategoryMealsScreen.js) I passed it down to the MealsNavigator.js file and then included the necessary associated files and put the options in there and it works.

Comment: `<MealsNav.Screen
                    name="CategoryMeals"
                    component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                    options={({ route }) => {
                        const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                        const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                        return {
                            title: selectedCategory.title,
                        };

                    }}
                />`

Comment: Yep. Thanks. And I'll keep this for future reference.